# What are the jQuery's draggable's true x and y coordinates respective to it's container and siblings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom, draggable

I'm trying to find the correct placement of images inside a container relative to the container and to eachother in order to provide colision detection and do some other useful stuff. Right now, lest imagine there is an HTML like:

```
<div id="imagesContainer">
    <div id="image1" ><img src="image1.png" /></div>
    <div id="image2" ><img src="image2.png" /></div>
    <div id="image3" ><img src="image3.png" /></div>
</div>
```

and some JavaScript code on document ready:

```
 var positions = {}; // should already contain some x,y pairs of other dragged imagges

 $('#imagesContainer div').draggable({
            cursor: 'crosshair',
            drag: function(event){
                var id = // get the draggable's id
                positions[id].x = //find the x of the draggable
                positions[id].y = //find the y of the draggable
                // do calculations on the positions
            } // drag:
        });
```

What are the true or correct values for the x and y coordinates of the div's relevant to the top left corner of their container, and how to set them and get them for future use (saving/restoring from database, etc.)?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: I wrote this question after trying to work out the jQuery UI demos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (according to [this page](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable)) that the position should be available as

```
$('your element').data('draggable').offset
```

Inside the `drag` callback you should be able to do

```
$('your element').draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        //Here you have available ui.position.top and ui.position.left
    }
});
```

Remember that `position` uses coordinates relative the parent element and `offset` relative to the page. Of course you can switch between the two by adding or subtracting the parent coordinates (relative to the page).

As for saving and restoring positions in the database, you can use the AJAX methods of jQuery, and is a completely different problem.

Comment: I think the .position() and .offset() return values relative to it's own element starting position, so when I start to move an image from the bottom up the top goes in minus, and it shouldn't since it still is in its container

Comment: Well, $(this).position() returns the initial coordinates, so you can just add them!

Comment: What I need is each element's coordinates in relation to their parent and to eachother. When the initial coordinates are returned, they are always (0,0) even since they are measured to the origin of drag.

Comment: $(this).position() DOES return the coordinates of whatever with respect to its parent. This has nothing to do with the draggable behaviour, see http://api.jquery.com/position/ Then you can sum this to the result of $(this).data('draggable').offset, which measures the displacement from the initial position.